# How to fix error "could not find function "setnafill""

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, data-visualization

I am going though [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/09/covid-19-exponential-growth-in-london/) project on COVID and trying to understand what the Author is doing to create to plot the actual time series and the forecast. But the code I copied and ran (see below) won't create the graph I need. I think it has something with the error `Error in setnafill(area_data, type = "const", fill = 0, cols = c("Daily.lab.confirmed.cases")) :  could not find function "setnafill"`   but I am not sure. Could someone help me out please.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
data_url <- "https://c19downloads.azureedge.net/downloads/csv/coronavirus-cases_latest.csv"
raw_data <- fread(data_url, check.names = TRUE)
area_name <- "London"
area_type <- "region"
area_data <- raw_data[
  Area.name == area_name &
    Area.type == area_type,,
  ][,Specimen.date := as.Date(Specimen.date)
    ][,c("Specimen.date","Daily.lab.confirmed.cases")][
      order(Specimen.date)
      ]
area_data <- merge(area_data,
                   data.table(Specimen.date = seq(
                     min(area_data[,Specimen.date]),
                     max(area_data[,Specimen.date]),
                     by = "1 day"
                   )), all = TRUE, by = "Specimen.date")
setkey(area_data, Specimen.date)
setnafill(area_data, type = "const", fill = 0,
          cols = c("Daily.lab.confirmed.cases"))
area_data[,roll_mean := frollmean(Daily.lab.confirmed.cases, n = 7, align = "right")]
######################################
###########Exponential model##########
######################################
area_data[,increasing := c(rep(NA,7), roll_mean[-(1:7)]- roll_mean[-((.N-6):.N)]>0)]
end_date <- area_data[order(Specimen.date, decreasing = TRUE)][increasing==TRUE,,][,
                                                                                   Specimen.date[1], by="increasing"]$V1
start_date <- area_data[order(Specimen.date, decreasing = TRUE)][
  increasing==FALSE & Specimen.date < end_date,,][,
                                                  Specimen.date[1], by="increasing"]$V1
exp_lm_data <- area_data[Specimen.date > start_date & Specimen.date <= end_date,,]
exp_lm_data[, days := 1:.N]
exp_lm <- lm(log(roll_mean)~ days, data = exp_lm_data)
exp_lm_data[,fitted_numbers := exp(fitted.values(exp_lm))]
predicted_data <- data.table(days=max(exp_lm_data$days)+1:28)
predicted_data[,Specimen.date := min(exp_lm_data$Specimen.date)+ lubridate::days(days)]
predicted_data[,predicted_numbers := exp(predict.lm(exp_lm, predicted_data))]
#####################################
m_area_data <- melt(area_data, id.vars="Specimen.date",
                    measure.vars = c("Daily.lab.confirmed.cases","roll_mean"))
exp_lm_data <- melt(dplyr::bind_rows(exp_lm_data, predicted_data),
                    id.vars="Specimen.date",
                    measure.vars = c("fitted_numbers","predicted_numbers"))
m_area_data <- rbind(m_area_data, exp_lm_data)
area_plot <- ggplot(m_area_data, aes(x = Specimen.date, y = value, fill = variable, color = variable))+
  geom_bar(data = subset(m_area_data, variable == "Daily.lab.confirmed.cases"),
           stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(data = subset(m_area_data, variable != "Daily.lab.confirmed.cases")) +
  labs(x="Specimen Date", y="Number of Confirmed Cases",
       fill = "", color = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ff0000","#05d153","#cad105","#000000"),
                                labels = c(sprintf("%s # Daily Confirmed cases",area_name),
                                                     "fitted","predicted","7 day average")) +
                                  scale_color_manual(values = c("#ff0000","#05d153","#cad105","#000000"),
                                                                 labels = c(sprintf("%s # Daily Confirmed cases",area_name),
                                                                                      "fitted","predicted","7 day average")) +
                                                                   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "4 weeks", date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d") +
                                                                   theme_bw() %+replace% theme(legend.position = "top",
                                                                                               legend.justification = "left")
```

Comment: What is your `packageVersion('data.table')` ? I am on `‘1.13.0’` and I have that function. Maybe you need to update your packages.

Answer (score 1):

`setnafill` is a function from the `data.table` package.
But it was only introduced in v1.12.4 (current version is v1.13.0)

So quite likely you have an outdated version of the `data.table` package
(as Ronak suggested)

So just use

```
install.packages("data.table")
```

to update the package.